# Ubuntu 23.10 Server installation issue: stop at acquiring and extracting image from cp ///tmp/tmp2xnglye4/mount

Tags: server, 23.10

I'm installing Ubuntu 23.10 Server on Vmware Workstation Player 17 and I got stuck with this issue: it keeps looping at acquiring and extracting image from cp ///tmp/tmp2xnglye4/mount.
Anyone who has had this issue before and any recommended solution is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: tyr oracle virtualbox instead